# Load more button in React

Tags: reactjs, load

I can't find a solution to my problem by myself. I find this nice tutorial with my problem solved: https://dev.to/narendersaini32/how-to-create-load-more-logic-in-react-474m but because I get my date already with a map its not working for me! Basically, I wanna make a load more button like in the link how to combinate with my solution, please any advice Thanks!

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import PortfolioCart from "./PortfolioCart";

const PortfolioList = ({ portfolio }) => {
  if (portfolio.length === 0) {
    return (
      <NoResults>
        <h3>
          <i className="fas fa-search" />
          &nbsp; There are no projects matching your parameters
        </h3>
      </NoResults>
    );
  }
  return (
    **<ListSection>
      <div className="portfolio-list">
        {portfolio.map((portfolios) => {
          return <PortfolioCart key={portfolios.id} portfolios={portfolios} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </ListSection>**
  );
};

export default PortfolioList;

const ListSection = styled.div`
  padding: 2rem 0;
  .portfolio-list {
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(270, 1fr));
    grid-row-gap: 2rem;
    grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 776px) {
    .portfolio-list {
      width: 90vw;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(330px, 1fr));
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .portfolio-list {
      width: 95vw;
      max-width: 1170px;
    }
  }
`;
const NoResults = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
`;
```

Comment: You need to write code to load more portfolios, like in your tutorial. Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: I did it like this! but all I get back was a lot of full lists and after button click load more lists..  `<ListSection>
  <div className="portfolio-list">
    {list.map(() => {
      portfolio.map((portfolios) => {
        return;
        <PortfolioCart key={portfolios.id} portfolios={portfolios} />;
      });
    })}
  </div>
</ListSection>; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can paginate your data locally

#### STEP 1 :

First create a local index variable to keep track of the number of times the load more button has been clicked . also add a page size and another state variable to hold the visible data.

```
const PAGE_SIZE = 10 ;  // or whatever you like

const [index , setIndex] = useState (0)

const [visibleData , setVisibleData] = useState ([])
```

#### STEP 2:

Then in load more button add onClick handler to handle the increase/decrease of index

```
<button onClick={ () => setIndex (index+1 )}>  Load More </button>
```

#### STEP 3:

Then when the index changes add more data

```
useEffect(() => {
    const numberOfItems = PAGE_SIZE * ( index +1 ); 

    const newArray = []; 

    for(let i= 0 ;i< portfolio.length ; i++ ){
      if(i < numberOfItems) 
          newArray.push(portfolio[i])
    }

    setVisibleData(newArray);
    
} , [index])
```

#### STEP 4:

Now render only visible datas

```
    <div className="portfolio-list">
        {visibleData.map((portfolios) => {
          return <PortfolioCart key={portfolios.id} portfolios={portfolios} />;
        })}
      </div>
```